# Jsoup getElementsByTag or select?

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

What is the difference between `getElementsByTag` and `select` in Jsoup (e.g. if getting links or image tags)? If they differ, how do I know which one to use in a certain situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general i would prefer `select` because it's definitely faster, more flexible and every select can be done in a single line.

I guess the only advantage of `getElementsBy...` is: you don't have to know the Selector API (or better: the syntax ... even if its realy easy to lern, check out: [Selector API doc](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)).